# JS string in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a javascript code that is given as

```
var info = document.getElementsByTagName("info");
```

Now I would like to get this js as string in Unity (as I am performing injection) and I am able to do it as

```
string information = "var info = document.getElementsByTagName('info');"
```

As you see I have to change the quote to single quote here. I do not want to do this. How do I avoid it and use the string as I get it?
Unfortunately, I have t

Comment: You can escape the double quotes with the backslash character, so `string information = "var info = document.getElementsByTagName(\"info\");";`

Comment: Yes but is there a way to avoid the backslash? I do not want to alter the string in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the double quotes.
You can do this using the backslash character:

```
string information = "var info = document.getElementsByTagName(\"info\");";
```

The extra \ characters are interpreted by the compiler and are never part of the actual string value. The strings value will not contain the backslashes. There is no way of expressing a string that contains quotes without escaping them.

Comment: Thanks but is there a way to avoid the backslash? I do not want to alter the string in any way.

Comment: @Sana You're misunderstanding escaping. The extra \ characters are interpreted by the compiler and are never part of the actual string value. The strings value will not contain the backslashes. There is no way of expressing a string that contains quotes without escaping them.
If my answer has answered your question could you please mark it as your accepted answer? Thanks

Comment: @SeanMcCafferty your comment in your answer could make it into part of the answer, it would improve it

Comment: @Cleptus I've updated my answer. Thanks for the feedback!